# My WD passport detected but showing size 0

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, file-corruption

Couple of days back while copying data my WD passport (1 TB) fell down. From that time if I connect it is showing 0 size in properties volume.

[image: screen shot].

Please help me to recover data.

Comment: [How do I recover lost/inacessible data from my storage device?](http://superuser.com/questions/241817/how-do-i-recover-lost-inacessible-data-from-my-storage-device)

Comment: I'm sorry to hear about this @rana_stack! :( Unfortunately, if the external WD My Passport fell down, it is most probably physically damaged now. I'd recommend you consider the assistance of [a professional data recovery company](http://support.wdc.com/warranty/datarecovery.aspx?lang=en) as they would be your best bet on getting those files back. Any data retrieving attempts by yourself are potentially dangerous to the data, especially in the presence of a hardware corruption. If you need further assistance, contact our [Customer Support](http://support.wdc.com/contact.aspx). Best of luck!